# An exception "The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received"

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I got an exception, I never got before when testing my application that uploads a file from ec2 to s3. The content is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadDigest; Request ID: 972CB8E04388AB20), S3 Extended Request ID: T7bmFnQ2RlGWlJD+aGYfTy97XZw88pbQrwNB8YCezSjyq6O2joxHRP/6ko+Q2zZeGewkw4x/90k=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:902)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3676)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1439)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What can I do to fix this bug? I used the same code as before in my application.

Answer (score 34):

I think I have solved my problem. I finally found that some of my files actually changed during the uploading. Because the file is generated by another thread, the uploading and generating is done at the same time. The file can not be generated immediately, and during the generating of a file, it may be uploading at the same time, the file actually changed during the uploading.

The md5 of file is created at the beginning of uploading by the AmazonS3Client, then the whole file is uploaded to the S3, at this time, the file is different from the file uploaded at beginning, so the md5 actually changed. I modified my program to a single-threading program, and the problem never turned up again.

Comment: yeah, there is probably 2 threads open:

`with open('foo.txt') as f:
    with open('bar.txt') as b:
        do_something()`

Answer (score 14):

Another reason for having this issue is to run a code such as this (python)

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
     self._bucket1.put_object(Key=key, Body=fd)
     self._bucket2.put_object(Key=key, Body=fd)
```

In this case the file object (fd) is pointing to the end of the file when it reaches line 3, so we will get the "Content MD5" error, in order to avoid it we will need to point the file reader back to the start position in the file

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
     bucket1.put_object(Key=key, Body=fd)
     fd.seek(0)
     bucket2.put_object(Key=key, Body=fd)
```

This way we won't get the aforementioned Boto error.

Comment: If you're using the `with` syntax and manipulating files, its likely this is your problem.  It was definitely mine.

Comment: My issue was ultimately similar, but did not look similar at first. I wanted to upload a full-size image and thumbnail image to S3. I used PIL to create a thumbnail. The problem was with `thumbnail = Image.open(image.file)` - when I created the thumbnail I was actually reading the original image file. So I needed to use `image.file.seek(0)` like the answer suggests

Comment: Yes, it is the case. I have added file.seek(0) and the error is gone and file is uploaded properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this error when I was doing something like this:

```
InputStream productInputStream = convertImageFileToInputStream(file);

InputStream thumbnailInputStream = generateThumbnail(productInputStream);

String uploadedFileUrl = amazonS3Uploader.uploadToS3(BUCKET_PRODUCTS_IMAGES, productFilename, productInputStream);

String uploadedThumbnailUrl = amazonS3Uploader.uploadToS3(BUCKET_PRODUCTS_IMAGES, productThumbnailFilename, thumbnailInputStream);
```

The *generateThumbnail* method was manipulating the *productInputStream* using a third party library.  Because I couldn't modify the third party library, I simply performed the upload first:

```
InputStream productInputStream = convertImageFileToInputStream(file);

// do this first... 
String uploadedFileUrl = amazonS3Uploader.uploadToS3(BUCKET_PRODUCTS_IMAGES, productFilename, productInputStream);

/// and then this...
InputStream thumbnailInputStream = generateThumbnail(productInputStream);

String uploadedThumbnailUrl = amazonS3Uploader.uploadToS3(BUCKET_PRODUCTS_IMAGES, productThumbnailFilename, thumbnailInputStream);
```

... and added this line inside my *generateThumbnail* method:

```
productInputStream.reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I've managed to find a completely different way of triggering this problem, which requires a different solution.

It turns out that if you decide to assign `ObjectMetadata` to a `PutObjectRequest` explicitly, for example to specify a `cacheControl` setting, or a contentType, then the AWS SDK mutates the `ObjectMetadata` instance to stash the MD5 that it computes for the put request.  This means that if you are putting multiple objects, all of which you think should have the same metadata assigned to them, you still need to create a new `ObjectMetadata` instance for each and every `PutObjectRequest`. If you don't do this, then it reuses the MD5 computed from the previous put request and you get the MD5 mismatch error on the second object you try to put.

So, to be explicit, doing something like this will fail on the second iteration:

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType("text/html");
for(Put obj: thingsToPut)
{
    PutObjectRequest por = 
        new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, obj.s3Key, obj.file);
    por = por.withMetadata(metadata);
    PutObjectResult res = s3.putObject(por);
}
```

You need to do it like this:

```
for(Put obj: thingsToPut)
{
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata(); // <<-- New ObjectMetadata every time!
    metadata.setContentType("text/html");
    PutObjectRequest por =
        new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, obj.s3Key, obj.file);
    por = por.withMetadata(metadata);
    PutObjectResult res = s3.putObject(por);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was that I used `ContentLength` in the params while executing `upload`. When it is commented out, it worked just fine.

```
const params = {
  Bucket: "",
  ContentType: "application/json",
  Key: "filename.json",
  // ContentLength: body.length,   <--- what I have commented out
  Body: body
};
await s3.upload(params).promise();
```

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into this problem. How I solved this:

I have a microservice that processes AWS SQS Messages. Each message would create multiple temporary files that would have to be uploaded to S3.

The issue was that the temporary files were named with fixed names without any salt added to them.

So between two messages, it was possible to rewrite the original file that was to be uploaded.

I fixed it by adding a random salt (this can be a UUID or the current time in millis depending on what you want) to the file names, after which the files were not being over-written and were successfully uploaded to S3.