# Amazon sdk java

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a local and custom implementation of an AWS infrastructure.

I use a Grizzley server to back my system. When I start it I have a bucket called "fake". This is the way I do it using AWS CLI:

```
aws --endpoint-url="http:127.0.0.1:8080" s3 FILE_PATH s3://fake
```

This works perfectly. My question is now how can I upload a file to that bucket using JAVA and not using the CLI?

Comment: The documentation explains how to do this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

Comment: Now it gives me another strange error like : The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadDigest; Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null

Comment: Add the code to the question so we that we might be able to help you with the error, or check if this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179310/a-exception-the-content-md5-you-specified-did-not-match-what-we-received-what/36198030